# get dropdownlist selected value into double variable asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, webforms

I need to pass Drop down list value to double variable.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="Drpdownlist" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12pt" Height="20px" Width="100px">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0.5">0.5 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1.5">1.5 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2.5">2.5 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3.5">3.5 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4.5">4.5 %</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5 %</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

There is variable

```
double rate = .5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
double rate;
double.TryParse(Drpdownlist.SelectedValue, out rate); // rate will be assigned if the conversion is successful
```

See more details about `double.TryParse` from the link below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should try This

```
double rate= Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString());
```